# Is "doubly in the bubbly" equivalent of "the devil is in the details"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity, idiom-meaning

Is `doubly in the bubbly` equivalent of `the devil is in the details`? How? What is the cultural background?

Comment: Never heard of that, but the second phrase is usually "the devil is in the detail" (singular).

Comment: [Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/search.html) has 'no-hit' for "doubly in the dubbly". Where did you see this?

Comment: @Rattler I see it in a book: section [1.2. On Dart](https://livebook.manning.com/book/flutter-in-action/chapter-1/20), second paragraph.

Comment: If that is the only place you can find it I would call it  a nonce, a one-off. BTW, you need to post examples of usage in the Q, or nobody will take it seriously.

Comment: I cannot find 'doubly in the bubbly' in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=doubly+in+the+bubbly). I cannot see it in [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=doubly+in+the+bubbly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=). It is not in [Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/search.html). I do not think this is a valid  idiomatic expression.

Comment: @Weather Vane non-count, surely?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth mass noun?

Comment: I don't go into the mass noun/non-count noun distinction that some seem to do – in my opinion, to defend the labelling of some nouns 'count nouns' etc. I believe it only makes sense to see countness as a function of usage, not POS (here nounness), so each usage is either count or non-count. Admittedly, even this can become a very tricky classification with some examples. "He received a basic education in maths and English" is easy compared to some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After exploring a few google sources it does not mean the same thing. It's just a silly reply:

> and [the devil] is **even more** (doubly) in **champagne** (bubbly).

From *The Manual of Detection* by Jedediah Berry

> She closed her eyes again, as though better to see her own thoughts. "All right, how about this? When one of us says, 'The devil's in the details,' the other must say 'And doubly in the bubbly.'"

and later:

> Instead the response to Emily’s secret phrase came uselessly to mind: *And doubly in the bubbly*.

And from *Wines for Sophisticated People*

> Remember, the proof is in the pudding, and doubly in the bubbly.

Comment: In vino veritas.